# Nautilus freezes every time I try to delete a file from my mounted disc

Tags: nautilus, mount, disk, delete

My problem is the following: Every time I try to delete a file from my auto-mounted drive Nautilus freezes up. First I get the prompt-screen saying ‘*Cannot move file to trash, do you want to delete immediately?*’. No matter what option I choose, Nautilus will freeze and stay frozen until I force it to quit.

I have no problem deleting files from my ‘system’ disk. And I tried deleting files on my mounted disk by using CLI and from Nautilus on an other computer over SSH, both methods work fine. It's just deleting that gives me problems. Copying, moving files around will work as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hold shift while deleting it has the same effect as bypassing the Trash. but that may not help with the issue if it is a bug. It is likely to still crash.

Comment: That works fine! I also enabled the “delete” option like Tinhed suggested which also works. Both are not a perfect solution since Nautilus can still crash if i’m not paying attention but it makes the situation much more workable. Thank you for that!

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance using nautilus elementary?. I am facing the same problem. Do you have a "delete" command when you right click on a file in nautilus.

Comment: Yes indeed, I’m using nautilus elementary. I have so for a while. The delete started acting up this morning. Can't see a ‘delete’ option but there is a ‘move to trash’ the same goes for my laptop. Which works fine.

Comment: You should mention that in your question then, as Nautilus Elementary is a different program than Nautilus.

Comment: In nautilus elementary, go to edit>>preferences>>behaviour. Check " include a delete command that bypasses trash" and try deleting directly to check whether that works.

Comment: “You should mention that in your question then, as Nautilus Elementary is a different program than Nautilus” I did not Nautilus Elementary differs from Nautilus. Thought Nautilus was the program Elementary the theme.